# set list as value in a column of a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, list, pandas

Let's say I have a dataframe `df` and I would like to create a new column filled with 0, I use:

```
df['new_col'] = 0
```

This far, no problem. But if the value I want to use is a list, it doesn't work:

```
df['new_col'] = my_list

ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index
```

I understand why this doesn't work (pandas is trying to assign one value of the list per cell of the column), but how can we avoid this behavior? (if it isn't clear I would like every cell of my new column to contain the same predefined list)

Note: I also tried: `df.assign(new_col = my_list)`, same problem

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You'd have to do:

```
df['new_col'] = [my_list] * len(df)
```

Example:

```
In [13]:
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5,3), columns=list('abc'))
df

Out[13]:
          a         b         c
0 -0.010414  1.859791  0.184692
1 -0.818050 -0.287306 -1.390080
2 -0.054434  0.106212  1.542137
3 -0.226433  0.390355  0.437592
4 -0.204653 -2.388690  0.106218

In [17]:
df['b'] = [[234]] * len(df)
df

Out[17]:
          a      b         c
0 -0.010414  [234]  0.184692
1 -0.818050  [234] -1.390080
2 -0.054434  [234]  1.542137
3 -0.226433  [234]  0.437592
4 -0.204653  [234]  0.106218
```

Note that dfs are optimised for scalar values, storing non scalar values defeats the point in my opinion as filtering, looking up, getting and setting become problematic to the point that it becomes a pain

Comment: Fast, efficient, thank you! I know it's not very efficient to store lists, but for machine-learning recommendations, it allows me to do the computations off-line (which is way off-topic)

Comment: You need to reconsider your data design model, I don't know what you're using but you can store a string in dfs fine and most machine learning apis support np arrays of strings as input

Answer (score 13):

Note that the accepted answer may lead to surprising behavior if you want to modify those lists:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([1, 2, 3], columns=['a'])
df['lists'] = [[]]* len(df)
df
   a lists
0  1    []
1  2    []
2  3    []
df.loc[df.a == 1, 'lists'][0].append('1')
df
   a lists
0  1   [1]
1  2   [1]
2  3   [1]
# oops
```

To avoid this you must initialize the `lists` column with a different list instance per row:

```
df['lists'] = [[] for r in range(len(df))] # note you can't use a generator
df.loc[df.a == 1, 'lists'][0].append('1')
df
   a lists
0  1   [1]
1  2    []
2  3    []
```

Don't be fooled by the display there, that 1 is still a string:

```
df.loc[df.a == 1, 'lists'][0]
['1']
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `DataFrame.apply`:

```py
In [1]:
df = pd.DataFrame([1, 2, 3], columns=['numbers'])
my_list = ['foo', 'bar']
df['lists'] = df.apply(lambda _: my_list, axis=1)
df

Out[1]:
   numbers       lists
0        1  [foo, bar]
1        2  [foo, bar]
2        3  [foo, bar]
```

Again, be aware that `my_list` is mutable and shared across the whole dataframe. To avoid that you can make a copy for each row:

```py
df['lists'] = df.apply(lambda _: my_list.copy(), axis=1)
```

Comment: Nice - still I think apply might be too slow compared to @EdChum's answer? Would be worth to have a comaprison (for biggish dfs)