# Set list in subset of pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

This is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38307489/set-list-as-value-in-a-column-of-a-pandas-dataframe) question, however differs in that I am concerned about a subset of the dataframe.

Suppose I have the following dataframe:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(42)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5), columns=['A'])
```

and I wish to have a column 'B' that has the value `["neg"]` for the negative values of A. However, when I do the following as was suggested in the linked question, I lose the list nature of what I was expecting.

```py
idx = df.A < 0  
df.loc[idx, "B"] = [["neg"]]*idx.sum() 
>>>
Out[17]: 
          A    B
0  0.496714  NaN
1 -0.138264  neg
2  0.647689  NaN
3  1.523030  NaN
4 -0.234153  neg
```

What am I doing wrong here? The only thing I can do in the meantime to fix this is to do: `df.loc[idx, 'B'] = df.loc[idx, 'B'].map(lambda x: [x])`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide a `pd.Series`, and you must supply the length of the entire DataFrame to associate `["neg"]` to any of the negative value(s):

```
df.loc[idx, "B"] = pd.Series([["neg"]]*len(df))
```

Result:

```
          A      B
0  0.496714    nan
1 -0.138264  [neg]
2  0.647689    nan
3  1.523030    nan
4 -0.234153  [neg]
```

Comment: How interesting. Why does this work? the RHS is of length 5 whereas the LHS has size 2. hmm python is strange. Thank you!

Comment: Yes, the right side is length 5 but the left side is saying only assign the list values when the idx condition is true. You're welcome!